# Expected ')' before '*' token

Tags: c++, class, include

So this is more of a syntax problem. I keep getting the error "Expected ')' before '*' token" on the line:

```
#include "CDocumentObserver.h"
#include "CViewPlayerDlg.h"

/*
 * Class:    CViewPlayer
 *
 */
class CViewPlayer : public wxWindow, public CDocumentObserver
{
public:
      CViewPlayer(CViewPlayerDlg *dlg);                //here
```

in CViewPlayer.h. The .cpp constructor looks like:

```
#include "CViewPlayer.h"
#include "wx/prec.h"
#include "CViewPlayerDlg.h"

using namespace std;

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(CViewPlayer, wxWindow)
    EVT_PAINT(CViewPlayer::OnPaint)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

CViewPlayer::CViewPlayer(CViewPlayerDlg *dlg) :
    wxWindow(dlg, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(dlg->GetDocument()->GetSize()), wxBORDER_SUNKEN),
    CDocumentObserver(dlg->GetDocument()), mStartTime(0), mPlayTime(0), mPlaying(false)
{
    SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(128, 128, 128));
    SetClientSize(GetDocument()->GetSize());
}
```

What causes this error? I thought it was that something was wrong in the constructor of the .cpp but I have no idea.

Comment: What does CViewPlayerDlg.h look like (in particular the class declaration of `CViewPLayerDlg`)?

Answer (score 5):

This typically means that a class has not been declared.

Check to see that `CViewPlayerDlg` is declared before you use it in the declaration of the `CViewPlayer` constructor, `CViewPlayer(CViewPlayerDlg* dlg)`.

A syntax error in a header file generally means that the error is in the header file, not the source (.cpp) file.